# Converting jquery + c# webservice to use GET instead of POST

Tags: c#, jquery, .net-3.5

I have a web-service which works fine using POST when communicating with it using ajax:

**Client-side:**

```
...
$.ajax({
    url: 'webservice.asmx/GetCount',
    type: 'POST',
    data: '{"theDate": "' + strDate + '"}',
...
```

**Server-side:**

```
...
[WebMethod()]
public double GetCount(string theDate)
{
...
```

How would I go about converting these so they make use of `GET` instead of `POST`?

I've tried changing the client-side part to `type: 'GET'`, but that gave an error so I am assuming I need to make some changes to the server-side part too?

Comment: `// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line.`
`// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add `[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true)]` to your webmethod

**Client-side:**

```
...
$.ajax({
    url: 'webservice.asmx/GetCount',
    type: 'GET',
    data: '{"theDate": "' + strDate + '"}',
...
```

**Server-side:**

```
...
[WebMethod()]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true)]
public double GetCount(string theDate)
{
...
```

Comment: Please see the error I get when I try this.  I have pasted the error in my question above.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following attribute to the method in question. I believe this should work:

```
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true)]
```